# No video feed from M600 Pro with mobile SDK

Tags: dji-sdk

I'm having trouble getting the video feed working from the M600 Pro.  It works fine in the DJI Go App so I know the feed is there, just not in my IOS app.  When we initially setup the app up for the M210, we needed to set bandwidth allocation to make it work, wondering if there is something like that needed for the M600 Pro?  Has anyone got that working?

Below is my code:

```
    if (product?.model == DJIAircraftModelNameMatrice600Pro) {
        DJISDKManager.videoFeeder()?.secondaryVideoFeed.add(self, with: nil)
    }

    VideoPreviewer.instance().start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes bandwidth could be an issue but also, other aspects of your setup could influence this blockage.  Without knowing your entire set-up this is a difficult question to answer since the M600 has a variety of variables.  The best thing to do is send a ticket to dev@dji.com with this issue but include - what cameras you are using, outline how you've made the connections, your setup for bandwidth, the reason you are using secondaryVideoFeed vs. Primary and any other details you can think of.